# Export KML file, google earth with fake time

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, kml, google-earth

I want to export my route to kml with fake time. I'm able to export route to kml file but there is no timestamp in kml file. Anyone can help ? I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a KML linestring containing all coordinates. (this step you probably already have)

then for each location create a placemark, where you can add custom attributes like timestamp.